# Can I hook a variable to a custom non-processing block?

Tags: python, gnuradio

I'm implementing a custom block for GRC which sends a command via serial to hardware. I need it to send the command each time a variable (e.g. a QT GUI range) changes. I'm quite new to GNU radio, so I don't know what would be the best approach. Do I need to derive my class from one of GNU radio's block classes (e.g. sync block) or should I create a custom block with a custom class and hook it up some other way into the system? How can I set it up so that the variable that changes calls my block's serial send function?

```py
MESSAGE_STR = 'SET '


class SerialBlock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ser = detect_device()

    def send_var(self, var):
        if self.ser is None:
            raise RuntimeError("No device found")

        bytes_to_write = bytearray(f"{MESSAGE_STR}{int(var)}", 'utf8')
        self.ser.write(bytes_to_write)
```

This is the class. If I want a change in the slider to call `send_var()` with the new value, how is the best course of action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a block's structure for GRC (in a [`.xml` (3.7)](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/XML_GRC) or [`.block.yml` (3.8)](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/YAML_GRC) file), you specify "callbacks" which are code that should be inserted in the GRC-generated code to be called whenever a parameter (of your block) which depends on a variable (that the GRC user created) changes, which is usually calling a "setter method". You just need to write such a callback.

I haven't personally written such a file for GR 3.8, but from examining examples, it looks like your `.block.yml` should resemble:

```
templates:
    [...other things in the templates section...]
    callbacks:
    - send_var(${var})
```

In 3.7 it would be the XML

```
<callback>send_var($var)</callback>
```

I wrote `var` to match your code, but it is actually the name of the *parameter* of your block, not the name of the variable. Your block definition doesn't know and doesn't need to know whether a parameter is a constant, a variable, or an expression containing a variable.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where this is documented? Did I just miss it, or can I contribute some documentation to GNU radio? I am still using 3.7 on Ubuntu, so the XML is perfect. However, I'm sure others in the future with the same question will appreciate your addition of the .yml format.

Comment: @LouisCloete I've added links to the wiki pages I found. I also searched the source code of GR for examples of files for the standard blocks. Unfortunately, I didn't find any reference documentation for the principles of operation of GRC.